# I need an Alert box on site load then vanish after 10 seconds

Tags: modal-dialog, alert, onload

I am about to start a work on a alert box or Modal, that will Pop-up when the sites loads and after 10 seconds it disappear.
I am looking for a html/css solution, if possible.
Can any body lend me an idea on how to achieve it?

Answer (score 0):

Here's a working example based on what you need as a modal popup.

```html
<html> 
  <head> 
    <title>Model popup box</title> 
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript"> 
      $(document).ready( function() {
        $('#modal').delay(10000).fadeOut();
      });
    </script>
  </head> 
  <body> 
    <div id=modal > Hello, i am a modal popup </div> 
  </body> 
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. This is what i was looking for.